# How to parametrize default values in informatica developer

Tags: informatica

I have simple mapplet in IDQ
Input Transformation with 2 string values 
Expression : simple Pass through
Out Transformation : 2 inputs from the input transformation and plus one more column with default value , say 'ABC'

instead of hard coding it in the output transformation how can i parametrize it

Answer (score 0):

As mapping level parameters are not yet available in developer tool, the only alternative is to source the data from another flat file and join this with the flow using a dummy join